# Java библиотеки

Tags: java

у меня есть две библиотеки от одного издателя, lib-5.1.jar и lib-7.1.2.jar, мне нужно в java проекте использовать в одной функции первую библиотеку, а в другой функции вторую. Про коллизии читал, проблема в том что у них одинаковый CLASSPATH. Я использую idea, буду благодарен за любую идею.

Comment: А что, в новой версии библиотеки нет старой функции? Может она переехала в другой класс?

Comment: В том то и проблема, что функции остались те же, только изменилась структура данных, поэтому нужно работать и со старыми данными и с новыми. А данные которые формирует библиотека являются зашифрованными.

Comment: а я бы сделал просто - отдельное приложение, которое работает с старой версией библиотеки и конвертирует в какой-либо читаемый формат (xml/json или даже простую сериализацию). А основная программа подхватывает и пишет в новую базу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если FQN совпадают, то всё, что вам остаётся — динамическое управление зависимостями.

1. Одна из реализаций спецификации [`OSGi`](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) — не советую использовать, пока вы точно не уверены, что без этого совсем никак не обойтись.
2. [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) — пожалуй, конкретно в данном случае — наиболее оптимальный вариант, хоть и не совсем красиво из-за рефлексии.

Выглядеть всё это будет примерно так:

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("file:///home/me/libs/some-library.jar") });
Class someClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.package.fqn.blabla.SomeClass");
// Теперь, используя рефлексию, можем вызывать методы, создавать экземпляры загруженного класса и т.д.
```

Comment: Это еще не все варианты. Можно выйти за пределы одной JVM :)